# error: constructor CatatanAdapter in class CatatanAdapter cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm new in Android Studio programming. I'm having trouble with my RecyclerView project. I already checked whole code, but I didn't find where is the problem. This keep give me an error "constructor CatatanAdapter in class CatatanAdapter cannot be applied to given types;".

My CatatanAdapter.java :

```
public class CatatanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatatanAdapter.ViewHolder> {

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
    holder.textViewJudulnya.setText(listItem.getJudulnya());
    holder.textViewCatatannya.setText(listItem.getCatatannya());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textViewJudulnya;
    public TextView textViewCatatannya;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewJudulnya = itemView.findViewById(R.id.judulnya);
        textViewCatatannya = itemView.findViewById(R.id.catatannya);

        }
    }
}
```

My Catatan.class :

```
public class Catatan extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catatan);
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(
                "Judulnya",
                "catatannya"
        );
        listItems.add(listItem);
    }
    adapter = new CatatanAdapter(listItems, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
}
```

My ListItem.java :

```
public class ListItem {
private String judulnya;
private String catatannya;
public ListItem(String judulnya, String catatannya) {
    this.judulnya = judulnya;
    this.catatannya = catatannya;
}
public String getJudulnya() {
    return judulnya;
}
public String getCatatannya() { return catatannya; }

}
```

Error:

```
error: constructor CatatanAdapter in class CatatanAdapter cannot be 
applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: List<ListItem>,Catatan
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `adapter = new CatatanAdapter(listItems, this);` but you have no such constructor in `CatatanAdapter` class. Add following code to your `CatatanAdapter` class.

```
ArrayList<ListItem > listItems = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;

public CatatanAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem > listItems, Context context) {
 this.listItems = listItems;
 this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Basically constructor are used to pass required arguments to next class.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add one constructor method -
or try to access the `ListItem` constructor wrongfully. without having seen the import statements, you might be mixing up `ListView` and `RecyclerView`.

```
public CatatanAdapter(ArrayList<ListItem> items, Context context) {
    this.setContext(context);
    this.setItems(items);
}
```

see [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView) ...

Comment: can you explain more?